# Problems using BigCommerce API to generate an order on the store

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am attempting to generate orders on my BigCommerce store using the BigCommerce API. I am using the code below to accomplish this. I am able to ping BigCommerce just fine and I get no errors in the php code. The problem is that it doesn't ever generate the order on my Bigcommerce store.

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
'store_url' => 'https://my-store.bigcommerce.com/',
'username'  => 'admin',
'api_key'   => 'XXXXXX'
));

$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();
if ($ping){ echo $ping->format('H:i:s');}

$createFields = array(
"customer_id" => 0,
"date_created" => $today,
"status_id" => 1,
"billing_address" => array(
        "first_name" => "Trisha",
        "last_name" => "McLaughlin",
        "company" => "",
        "street_1" => "12345 W Anderson Ln",
        "street_2" => "",
        "city" => "Austin",
        "state" => "Texas",
        "zip" => "78757",
        "country" => "United States",
        "country_iso2" => "US",
        "phone" => "",
        "email" => "elsie@example.com"),
"shipping_addresses" => array(
        "first_name" => "Trisha",
        "last_name" => "McLaughlin",
        "company" => "",
        "street_1" => "12345 W Anderson Ln",
        "street_2" => "",
        "city" => "Austin",
        "state" => "Texas",
        "zip" => "78757",
        "country" => "United States",
        "country_iso2" => "US",
        "phone" => "",
        "email" => "elsie@example.com"),
"external_source" => "POS",
"products" => array(
        "product_id" => "90",
        "quantity" => "1"));

print_r(Bigcommerce::createOrder($createFields));
```

What am I missing?

Am I using the BigCommerce API incorrectly?

Any help on figuring out why my code isn't generating orders on my Bigcommerce store would be awesome!

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: I don't see any errors at all. Just have time readout from the ping. Is there a way to display Bigcommerce errors?

Comment: Not php errors. What is the response from the Bigcommerce Orders API?

Comment: I am getting a "The field 'products' is invalid" error message.

Answer (score 1):

The `products` property needs to be a nested array, where each individual product within the parent `products` array must exist as its own array:

```
"products" => array(
  0 => array(
    "product_id" => int,
    "quantity"   => int
  ),
  1 => array(
    "product_id" => int,
    "quantity"   => int,
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from the "quantity" parameter in the products array. It's expecting an int instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, removing the quotes from the "quantity" parameter still results in the same error: `13:35:24array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["status"]=> int(400) ["message"]=> string(32) "The field 'products' is invalid." } }`

Comment: Does the product have product options? If so you need to pass in the ID of the option as well as the selected value. See [this documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders/order/products) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
products'=>array(
'product'=>array(
'product_id'=>90
'quantity'=>1
```

- product_id and quantity are type int and should not have quotes ""
- You need a product array in your Products array

Answer (score 0):

Set Your Array Like This:

```
$createFields=Array(
                   "customer_id" => 0,
                   "status_id"=> 10,
                   "billing_address"=> [
                        "first_name"=> "Trisha",
                        "last_name"=> "McLaughlin",
                        "company"=> "",
                        "street_1"=> "12345 W Anderson Ln",
                        "street_2"=> "",
                        "city"=> "Austin",
                        "state"=> "Texas",
                        "zip"=> "78757",
                        "country"=> "United States",
                        "country_iso2"=> "US",
                        "phone"=> "",
                        "email"=> "a@example.com"
                    ],
                    "shipping_addresses"=>[ 
                        [

                            "first_name"=> "Trisha",
                            "last_name"=> "McLaughlin",
                            "company"=> "Acme Pty Ltd",
                            "street_1"=> "566 Sussex St",
                            "street_2"=> "",
                            "city"=> "Austin",
                            "state"=> "Texas",
                            "zip"=> "78757",
                            "country"=> "United States",
                            "country_iso2"=> "US",
                            "phone"=> "",
                            "email"=> "a@example.com"
                        ]],
                    "products"=>[
                        [ 
                            "product_id"=> 90,
                            "quantity"=>1,
                              // "name"=> "data",
                        ],
                        ],

                    "external_source"=> "POS"
                );
```